# How to add MarginBottom to a BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

This is what i have so far for my BottomSheetFragment. I need to add an offset marginBottom to the bottomSheet. Setting up the margin on its view, adds:

```
  @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layou_menu_more, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        BottomSheetBehavior<View> mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(((View) contentView.getParent()));
        if (mBottomSheetBehavior != null) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
            contentView.requestLayout();
        }

        View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0,0,0,90);
        bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(params);
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogINterface) {
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
               // dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        });
        return dialog;
    }
```

creates this view:

[image]

as you can see, the 90dp margin ends up as the padding for BottomSheet. 
How can i apply an offset `marginBottom` to the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`?

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? Can we set marginBottom for BottomSheatDialog?

Answer (score 1):

> **Do the following to use the  Margin** 
>  1: first, make your BottomSheetDialogFragment.class with XML  
>  2: put Margin to Style
> and set up on your BottomSheetDialogFragment.class
>
> ---

**Style**

```
   <!-- Stuff to make the bottom sheet with round top borders  | margins top right left bottom-->
    <style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
    </style>

    <style name="bottomSheetStyleWrapper" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>

    </style>
```

**In final must set on BottomSheetDialogFragment.class**

note : set on onCreate in BottomSheetDialogFragment.class

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //bottom sheet round corners can be obtained but the while background appears to remove that we need to add this.
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.BottomSheetDialog);
        
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout for your first ViewGroup.
like this, and set margin in your second ViewGroup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_60"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_66"">

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CardView` as the root view for your bottomsheet and then define
`app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`
That should give it a margin from the bottom.
Additionally you can define `app:cardElevation="5dp"` to make it bigger depending on how much big you want it

Answer (score -2):

Use `RelativeLayout` rather than `FrameLayout` for the parent View if you can.

By doing so you can easily achieve your goal.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If you have to use `FrameLayout`, create an additional container with `height = MATCH_PARENT` and `gravity = BOTTOM` and place your View there.

Comment: this issue doesn't talk about RelativeLayout or FrameLayout  just an issue about margin and we solve must use a Style and set on  BottomSheetDialogFragment. maybe you don't know my question clear so I write my solution in answer